# Two Query with if statement

Tags: mysql

I used an if condition in a query sql. But in the processing part I want to use a MySQL query like this example:

```
IF (select ( test= str )like'ZAG,TUN,TOZ,TAT,SOS,SIL,SFX,SBO,RNC,BAR,BEJ,BIZ,BSC,GAB,GAF,JEN,KAI,KAS,KEB,KEF,MAH,MED,MON,NAB')=1 THEN SET co=update  incident set test=(select substring(trim(substring_index(Test,'sur',-1)),1,3) as n1 ) WHERE  Affected_CI in('other ci','Other CI');
```

I launched but no results and it shows me a problem at the:

> 'co=update...

Thanks.

Comment: If its not a part of stored procedure or trigger you can not use the if condition like you have now.

Comment: i will use it in a function

Comment: The syntax that you have used is not correct for sure. It would be easy to provide a solution if you update the question and add some sample data and what function should do with those data with some example.

Comment: I used  a column 'Title' in a table 'incident'.
This column contains some information .Among this information, three character that indicates the region .these three character are usually found after ('on', ':'). I want to execute a function (mysql) which allows:
1) if the three character taken from the 'Title' column, which are located after 'on',  are( kef or bej or jen) so the result will be stored in a column 'test' in the same table.
2) if the first is not achieved then takes the three character which are located after ':' and stored in a column 'test1' in the same table.